# Regular Expression Pattern for this

Tags: regex

E.g.:

```
url = "http://abc.xyz.com/name=test&account=google&search=google"
```

At Present I am using below regular Expression to replace DNS name
"^((?:http?:(?:\/\/)?)?)[^\/]*";

It is working fine but it is replacing "http://abc.xyz.com/" with other string but I want to replace only domain name only ptotocal info should be as it is

i.e. abc.xyz.com with other string not http://

Ex:

String re = "/^(?:(?!https?:\/\/|\/).)+/gm";
 String str = "http://abc.xyz.com/name=test&account=google&search=google";

```
String subst = "www.xyz.com";
```

`System.out.println(str.replace(re, subst));`

Actual : "http://abc.xyz.com/name=test&account=google&search=google"
Expected : "http://www.google.com/name=test&account=google&search=google"

o/p not working

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Basically you just want everything up to the first forward slash?

Comment: I'm assuming you can't just replace "abc.xyz.com" with "www.xyz.com" using whatever literal replace functions are in your language? (eg. `str_replace("abc.xyz.com","www.xyz.com",$subject)`)

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?:(?!https?:\/\/|\/).)+
```

You can try this.Replace by `www.xyz.com`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/49

```
var re = /^(?:(?!https?:\/\/|\/).)+/gm;
var str = 'abc.xyz.com/name=test&account=google&search=google"\nhttp://abc.xyz.com/name=test&account=google&search=google"\nhttps://abc.xyz.com/name=test&account=google&search=google"\ntextile.trails.com/…{crea}&secure‌​_id=[SECURE_ID]&position={heigherposition}&search_device={network}&device={device‌​}&match_type={matchtype}';
var subst = 'www.xyz.com';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: Thanks for response but one criteria is missing actually url started with "http". I tried it is not working.

Comment: I am applying same pattern to this URL but it is not working Can you please help me for exact Regular Expression.Thanks in advance  <br/>         http://textile.trails.cgu.in/sd_prod.xls?key=[KEY]&m=[MODE_TEST]&acd={crea}&secure_id=[SECURE_ID]&position={heigherposition}&search_device={network}&device={device}&match_type={matchtype}<br/> http://textile.trails.com should replace with www.trails.com <br/> Please help me out the correct pattern

Comment: String s = "http://textile.trails.com/sd_prod.xls?key=[KEY]&m=[MODE_TEST]&acd={crea}&secure_id=[SECURE_ID]&position={heigherposition}&search_device={network}&device={device}&match_type={matchtype}";

        String smRegexSt = "^([^\"]*\"(?:http?:(?:\\/\\/)?)?)[^\\/]*";
        Pattern smExtRegex = Pattern.compile(smRegexSt);

        Matcher matcher = smExtRegex.matcher(s);
        String url = null;

        if (matcher.find()) {
             url = matcher.replaceAll("www.trails.com");
        }

       System.out.println(url);
    
I am using above code but it is printing value as "null"

Comment: thanks now its working. but one last help required I have different URLs of same pattern but I want to replace only http://textile.trails.com to http://www.textile.com

Comment: I added below can you please have a look and let me know

Comment: I tried but it is not working in JAVA just give me last pattern eventhough if it is hardcoded with one string. See my requirement below and give me..its bit urgent thanks for your support..

Comment: @kiranreddy `^((?:https?:(?:\/\/)?)?)[^\/]*`and replace by `$1www.trails.com` this should work

Comment: Can you please modify the same pattern with hard coded string as "textiles" please do needful..thnaks

Comment: @kiranreddy not getting you.Please modify your question and list down all the needs.

Comment: What I am asking is at present Regular expression replacing the content in middle of http://...../ Apart from that if http://..../ and word like "textile" then only replace the content

Comment: Hi I need one more help..I updated the content above can you please help me to resolve that issue?

Comment: @kiranreddy try http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/49 also do not forget to accept an ans if it is correct.

Comment: Sure..this pattern is not replacing with destination string.. not working..  matcher.find() method returning false..

Comment: @kiranreddy you have to use `var result = str.replace(re, subst);` no find.

Comment: Still it is not replacing I am using like below System.out.println(s.replaceAll(regExpr,
                "www.xyz.com" )) I think need to change regex?

Comment: it was not working, I update the example above which I tried..I think we need to chnage bit in regex..please help me..sorry for trouble you..

Comment: @kiranreddy you said `http` should not be replaced.Now you re asking for replacememt?????

Comment: yes, my question is if an url like this  http://.../  then I want to replace in between content not http://. that is my question I asked same thing..

Comment: it is replacing '/' as well it should be .com/name but both are combined here see this "www.xyz.comname"

Comment: one more thing I am using same pattern in Java but it is behaving differently. So do we need to chnage anything else. At present I am using Pattern concept in java. Thanks In advance..

Comment: Hi can you please give me any clue why it behaving like  that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

Search for: `(https?://)?\w+(.*)`
and replace with: `$1www$2`

Comment: no this one also not working..Can you please have a look at above requirement once?